# socket.io the room in the rooms dictionary is 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, serversocket

so I'm emitting an event from my client that sends a string containing the socket/roomID I'm trying to connect to in it. When the data is received, it's handled by this code on the server side:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//runs when the user connects to the server
function onConnection(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  // socket.join('some room');
  console.log('Created Room: ' + socket.id);

  socket.emit("RoomID", socket.id);
  socket.on("location", (receivedString) => {
    // socket.emit("RoomID", socket.id);
    socket.to(socket.id).emit("redirectLocation", receivedString);
    console.log('\nReceived the following data from socket "' + socket.id + '": ' + receivedString);
    console.log('The amount of people in this room is ' + io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(socket.id).size + '.');
  });

  //runs when the user is trying to join a specific room
  socket.on("joinRoom", (roomIdentifier) => {
    console.log('The room identifier is: ' + roomIdentifier);
    console.log('The room is already in the rooms array: ' + io.sockets.adapter.rooms[String(roomIdentifier)]);
    if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomIdentifier]) {
    socket.join(roomIdentifier);
    } else {
      console.log(socket.id + 'tried to join ' + roomIdentifier + 'but the room does not exist.');
    };
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', onDisconnection);
}

//runs when the user disconnects from the server
function onDisconnection(socket){
  console.log('a user disconnected');
}

//runs when the socket manager registers a connection
io.on('connection', onConnection);

//Runs when a new room was created
io.of("/").adapter.on("create-room", (room) => {
  console.log(`room ${room} was created`);
});

io.of("/").adapter.on("join-room", (room, id) => {
  console.log(`socket ${id} has joined room ${room}`);
});

http.listen(port, () => console.log('listening on port ' + port));
```

I don't know why it's coming out as undefined--I thought maybe it was because the rooms dictionary wasn't supposed to have a string or something as a key but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Are rooms created at any point elsewhere in the code?

Comment: @Mehdi Oh yeah, when someone connects to the socket server, a room is automatically created for them--I updated my answer to show my whole node.js file. As long as I understand correctly, when a user establishes a connection to the socket server, a new 'default room' is created with the same ID as their socket.id--Now, if instead they want to join a specific socket room, they send a roomIdentifier which should place them into the correct room (using the join function)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in the code shared:

#### Check whether a room already exists

The following command shows that `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` is a JavaScript [`Map` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```
console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms)
// returns [object Map]
```

To check whether the Map contains the room name, the `Map.has(key)` should then be used, instead of `Map[key]`:

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms.has(roomIdentifier)
```

Once the room existence checks are adapted as above, the code still fails to let users join a room, as explained below.

#### Joining a room

The `if` statement lets the user join a room only if the room already exists, and does nothing otherwise. As a consequence, rooms are never created, and hence no user can ever join any of them.

```
if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms.has(roomIdentifier)) {
  socket.join(roomIdentifier);
} else {
  console.log(socket.id + 'tried to join ' + roomIdentifier + 'but the room does not exist.');
  // Socket.join is not executed, hence the room not created.
};
```

`socket.join` should be executed outside of the `if` statement. The `if` statement can probably be removed from the code, unless some specific action needs to be taken depending on it.

```
if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms.has(roomIdentifier)) {
  // action when room already exists
} else {
  console.log(socket.id + 'tried to join ' + roomIdentifier + 'but the room does not exist.');
  // action when room is new
};

// join the room in any case
socket.join(roomIdentifier);
```

Comment: this is really great, but my question is, isn't the room already created to a new socket server when the initial onConnection() function is run? And then from there I have to run joinRoom() to switch the user to a different socket?

Comment: Each socket is connected automatically to its own room identified by `socket.id`. You do not need to run `join` for this. Checkout the docs.  https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/index.html#Default-room . You may want to clarify what should happen for each connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomId)` io.sockets.adapter.rooms returns a *Map Object* so using `io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId]` **returns undefined**.